# I'm currently fasting, while vegan, is there anything diet related I should address when I finish?

Tags: weight-management

To lose weight, I have started on both portion control and fasting on odd nights. I do not know if there are nutritional problems that could arise from this type of dieting. Are there specific nutritional recommendations for vegans when recovering from intermittent fasting?

Answer (score 3):

I found this question a little broad, my interpretation is: Any special food/activity should one perform after fasting?  I grew up in a religion that typically fasts, and became vegan 4-5 years ago and found no physical difference.  The real difference was new mental awareness.  Fasting sort of paused my unintentional acceptance of the cycle of eating, and veganism also paused my unintentional eating of animals.  The more I fast, I realized, the pain of hunger starts mentally long before one's body will actually be in any danger.  And...fasting allowed me the pause in time to see the pain of hunger can subside, and one can just forget about food.

All of this is a long winded way of me saying, I guess regardless of veganism, or not, leave some integration time before you get back to post-fasting business as usual.  Integrate what you felt during fasting, and let it shine new light on what you need vs. what you want.  Allow yourself to feel gratitude that your elected fasting pain can be lifted at any time, which for some fasting is not elected (starvation).

Hope this helps, sorry if you were looking more for a specific diet add.  I would say after fasting would be a good opportunity to tweak your diet by one item.  Like say I stopped eating lentils after fasting once and was able to perceive I had a lot less gas.  And I subsequently have proven that adding it back it in is a gas.  Pun intended.

Comment: Thank you for the lentils tip.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately "intermittent fasting" is a bit vague. Is it 16/8? Or a 7 day fast? For the former, I don't change anything about how I eat. For the latter, I go with something light like salad, with a small amount of side tofu/protein. I'm very slow/careful about reintroducing carbs. The second meal is usually something fatty, might even call it ketogenic. I don't go back to "normal" eating until at least the next day.